# Filebeat with custom logfile and kubernetes metadata to elasticsearch and kibana

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

Our applications are deployed in AWS EKS cluster, and for certain reasons we need to write our app logs to separate file lets say ${POD_NAME}.applog instead of stdout (we mounted /var/log/container/ to the pod /log folder and app writes /log/${POD_NAME}.applog ). And we are using filebeat to send the logs to Elasticsearch and we are using Kibana for visualization. Our filebeat config file looks like this

```
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: log
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.applog
      json.keys_under_root: true
      json.message_key: log
      processors:
        - add_cloud_metadata:
        - add_host_metadata:
```

This is working fine, but we realised we are missing the kuberenetes metadata in ES and Kibana. But we are getting kuberenetes metadata when we include `-type: conatainer`.

```
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: log
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.applog
      json.keys_under_root: true
      json.message_key: log
    - type: container
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
```

So we tried adding the config like this

```
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: log
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.applog
      json.keys_under_root: true
      json.message_key: log
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            in_cluster: true
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
        - add_cloud_metadata:
        - add_host_metadata:
```

Still we are not getting the kuberenetes metadata in kibana. I tried with all trial and error method, but nothing works.

Can someone please help me how to get Kubernetes metadata with custom logfile in filebeat.

Answer (score 0):

We meet the same issue under EKS 1.24, there is no kubernetes metadata in the log entry. Per doc [Add Kubernetes metadataedit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.17/add-kubernetes-metadata.html),  we solve it through the following config under filebeat version `7.17.8`.

```yaml
- type: container
  paths:
    - /var/log/pods/*/*/*.log
  exclude_files: ['filebeat.*',
                  'logstash.*',
                  'kube.*',
                  'cert-manager.*']
  processors:
    - add_kubernetes_metadata:
        in_cluster: true
        host: ${NODE_NAME}
        matchers:
          - logs_path:
              logs_path: '/var/log/pods/'
        default_indexers.enabled: false
        default_matchers.enabled: false
        indexers:
          - pod_uid:
        matchers:
          - logs_path:
              logs_path: '/var/log/pods/'
              resource_type: 'pod'
```

The default indexer and matcher should be disabled. And the `pod_uid` indexers could identify the pod metadata using the UID of the pod. You could find the `logs_path` matchers config from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.17/add-kubernetes-metadata.html#_logs_path)

Comment: Thanks @zangw for reply. Currently we halted with that approach. Will definitely try again when we are ready.